# G3W framework with QGIS Server

Tags: qgis, postgis

I installed the G3W framework a few days ago. I have created a QGIS project which reads data from PostGIS. The approach I've used is that of a single table that has 42000 records. This table is the result of a join. Loading is extremely slow and geometry points show after some time. I guess that the approach I use is wrong and that I have to do the joins inside the QGIS project by loading the tables separately. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

When I have to use huge tables that come from a high cost join then I prepare a materialized view that comes from this join. Then I set up an automated task that is refreshing this MV after data change or i.e. everyday at night.